# how to see/extract model flows evolution when solve a model in a Scilab function?

Tags: function, modeling, ode, scilab

I wrote the Lotka Voterra model (prey-predator) as a Scilab function and solved it with ODE. My problem is that I want to see the flows evolution. I found a solution by including flows in the resolution (in the script below only for one) but it’s really “heavy”. Anyone has a better solution?

```
//parameters
x=[0.04,0.005,0.3,0.2]
n = x(1);//birth rate of prey
c = x(2);//capture rate
e = x(3);//energy from capture
m = x(4);//death rate or predator

Tmax=100; // maximum time of simulation 
dt=0.01; // step of time 
t=0:dt:Tmax; //simulation time definition 
Ci = [20,30,0]'; //initial conditions (including for 1 flow)

//Lotka Volterra model
function [dy]=LV(t, y, n, c, e, m)
    GrowthP = n * y(1)
    IngestC = c * y(1) * y(2)
    MortC = m * y(2)
    dy(1) = GrowthP - IngestC
    dy(2) = IngestC * e - MortC
    dy(3) = IngestC //here one flow in ode
endfunction 

//resolution
sol=ode(Ci,0,t,LV)

//dataframe creation to stock data
soldef=zeros(3,10001);

//for the line 3 and form 2 to the last data it take the value, 
//remove the one of the previous time step and store it in soldef
for i = 2:length(sol(3,:))
    soldef(3,i)=sol(3,i)-sol(3,i-1);
end

//complete the dataframe with the stock
soldef(1:2,:)=sol(1:2,:)
```

Thanks for the interest and the time you give to my problem (and sorry for my English)

Answer (score 0):

If you want animated display of your results, you can use the code below to plot more and more data on a graph:

```
[row,col]=size(soldef);
scf(0);
clf(0);
plot2d(soldef(:,1:2)',rect=[0,0,col,max(soldef)]);  //plot first 2 points
en=gce();   //handle of the graphic entities
for i=3:col   //plot more and more points
  en.children(1).data=[1:i;soldef(3,1:i)]';   //update data matrices
  en.children(2).data=[1:i;soldef(2,1:i)]';
  en.children(3).data=[1:i;soldef(1,1:i)]';
  //you can save the frames here...
  xpause(1e4);    //wait some time if amination is too fast
end
```

If you save all the graphs (with e.g.`xs2gif()`), with an external application (google for "gif maker") you can even make a .gif animation of your results to embedd in a webpage or presentation.